# prestashop show helper form checkbox checked

Tags: php, html-helper, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop module I want to show a checkbox checked. For that I just took the helper class methods like this

```
$display_settings = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l( 'Display Settings' ),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'display',
                    'values' => array(
                        'query' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'show_header',
                                'name' => $this->l('show header'),
                                'val' => '1',
                                'checked' => 'checked'
                            ),
                        ),
                        'id' => 'id',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    )
                ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l( 'Save Display Settings' ),
                    'class' => 'button pull-right',
                    'name' => 'save-main-display-settings',
                )
            ),
        );
```

but this one is showing only checkbow (not checked). I tried to chnage val into 0,1. But it did not worked for me. So can someone tell me how to make a checkbox checked in helper class. Any help or suggestions will be really  appreceable. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please remove 'checked' => 'checked' it is not necessary. Rest of your code is okay - but it is only FORM structure definition, if you want to fill it with data (checked checkbox is data definition not structure) **you need to provide data to HelperForm**.

To make checkbox checked set it value by:

```
$helper = new HelperForm();
$helper->fields_value['display_show_header'] = true;
```

The name "display_show_header" is concatenation of your names "display" and "show_header", you can also see this name in firebug when look at rendered checkbox.

Comment: note: strings `"1"` / `"0"` also works as true / false => checked / unchecked

Answer (score 2):

A full example:

```
/**
 * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
 */
protected function renderForm()
{
    $helper = new HelperForm();
    // ...
    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFieldsValues(),
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
    );

    return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
}
/**
 * Helper Function to fill Checkbox Fields with Data
 */
public function getConfigFieldsValues()
{
    $fields_value = array();

    $shop_groups = $this->getShopGroups();
    foreach($shop_groups as $shop_group) {
        $shop_group_id = $shop_group['id_shop_group'];

        $subshops = $this->getSubshops($shop_group['id_shop_group']);
        foreach($subshops as $subshop) {
            $shop_id = $subshop['id_shop'];
            $fields_value['mwdsubshoporderstate_' . $shop_group_id . '_' . $shop_id] = $this->getStatus($shop_id);
        }
    }

    return $fields_value;
}
/**
 * Create the structure of form.
 */
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    $form = array();
    $form_input = array();

    $shop_groups = $this->getShopGroups();
    foreach($shop_groups as $shop_group) {
        $subshops = $this->getSubshops($shop_group['id_shop_group']);

        $form_input[] = array(
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'label'     => $this->l($shop_group['name'] . ' :'),
            'desc'   => $this->l(''),
            'name'      => 'mwdsubshoporderstate_' . $shop_group['id_shop_group'],
            'values'    => array(
                'query' => $subshops,
                'id'    => 'id_shop',
                'name'  => 'name',
            )
        );
    }

    $form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Diverse Einstellungen'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
            ),
            'input' => $form_input,
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Speichern'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $form;
}
```